# Angular 1.0 How to import a TypeScript module

Tags: angularjs, typescript, import

I have a Angular App written in JavaScript and then I found a external Module (for integrating jquery.dynatree) here:

https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/blob/master/hawtio-web/src/main/webapp/app/tree/js/treePlugin.ts

Now I want to include this module into my Project, but Angular has problems to read/compile this script.

What I can do, to solve this problem?

PS: I have already installed the npm-compiler (not sure I need that) with this command: npm install typescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use gulp module [gulp-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-typescript) to compile your typescript module to javascript and then import it as normal javascript.

Comment: Thank very much. I have complied the module now and it looks fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Since your project is a JavaScript project, not a TypeScript one, you want to only include .js files in your project.

Try to find a JavaScript version of this file first. If you don't find one, compile this TypeScript file to JavaScript, and then only include the .js file in your project.

Comment: Ok, but do you know how to compile a single file? And what I need to do this?